# Laravel 5 Generating dynamic objects from string

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I have the following directory structure (only the important files shown):

```
app/
 - Http/                        
   - Controllers/
     - MyController.php         // namespace App\Http\Controllers
 - Utils/
   - InternalUtils/
     - Utility1.php             // namespace App\Utils\InternalUtils
     - Utility2.php             // namespace App\Utils\InternalUtils
     - ...
   - MyUtility.php             // namespace App\Utils
```

I am following the standard PSR-4 namespacing available in Laravel 5.

In the `MyUtility.php` file I am trying to use the following:

```
use InternalUtils\Utility1;
use InternalUtils\Utility2;
(new Utility1);   // works
$className = 'Utility1';
(new $className);   // throws Class 'Utility1' not found
```

Note that each Utility file is namespaced and contains a class name with the same name as `Utility1`.

The dynamic generation of objects is failing.
Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Comment: try to use **use \App\Utils\InternalUtils\Utility1;**

Comment: you have to import the class by full namespace , so instead of `use InternalUtils\Utility1;` you have to use `App\Utils\InternalUtils\Utility1;`

Comment: @NoNameProvided That does not work either.

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen I tried importing via full namespace, but does not work. This is weird because I am able to use the full namespace from the controller and create an instance of the class.

Comment: clear your compiled file via artisan command

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen `php artisan clear-compiled; php artisan optimize`. Issue not fixed.

Comment: @NoNameProvided I'm trying to dynamically create an object via string. Please check the updated question

Comment: @activatedgeek I appreciate this is a very old thread but I'm up against a very similar problem, did you ever work out an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Please do as following

In your Utility1.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Utils\InternalUtils;

Class Utility1 
{
    //code ....
}
```

In order to use the Utility1 class in MyUtility class, you can import full namespace

```
<?php 

namespace App\Utils;

use App\Utils\InternalUtils;   

class MyUtility 
{
    //other code 

    $utility1 = new InternalUtils\Utility1();
    $utility2 = new InternalUtils\Utility2();
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't allow you to import full namespaces!

Comment: @Jeemusu That's just how PHP works (or doesn't work). `use App\Utils\InternalUtils;` doesn't import anything.

Comment: @activatedgeek, change the `use` in your `MyUtility` class to `use App\Utils\InternalUtils\Utility1;` . Then initialise it with `new Utility1();`. Then do the same for utility2

Comment: @Jeemusu If I try generating the object dynamically from a string, this fails. Any ideas?